# Android Fragment Memory issue

Tags: android, exception, memory, fragment

I have `Fragment` in `ViewPager`.
In onCreate() of Fragment, I called method below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.group = groupManager.getGroup();
    if (group == null) throw new NullPointerException("...");
    ...
}
```

If group is null, throw NullPointerException. but, this exception is not occurred. Instead of, in onActivityCreated(),

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    group.getXX; // NullPointerException
    ...
}
```

This exception is occurred sometimes, not always. I don't know why caused the exception in onActivityCreated() not onCreate().

Thank you for your answer.

- I think this is android memory issues, but not sure. Is the `group` when memory is low fragment is drawn back to be replaced with null?
- Added : SourceFile:55 is line of `group.getXX` in below.

  Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
  xx.xxx.xxxFragment.onActivityCreated (SourceFile:55)
  android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (SourceFile:1794)
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (SourceFile:967)
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (SourceFile:1126)
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (SourceFile:1108)
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (SourceFile:1917)
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (SourceFile:544)
  com.dunamu.stockplus.TrackingSherlockFragmentActivity.onStart (SourceFile:9)
  com.dunamu.stockplus.BaseActivity.onStart (SourceFile:123)
  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1171)
  android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:5285)
  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2178)
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2255)
  android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:142)
  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1203)
  android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5118)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)

Comment: please post full code with logcat

Comment: Do you set group to null somewhere?

Comment: I never set group to null. I think this is android memory issues, but not sure. If fragment redraw to low memory, onCreate() is not called again?